# JavaFX WebView / WebEngine

Tags: webview, javafx, java-8, javafx-webengine

I have a `JavaFX` `WebView` that is being updated with background messages and executes scripts to update the page.

```
webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
  new ChangeListener<State>() {
    public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
        if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
            try {
                webEngine.executeScript("foo1();");  
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // JSException: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This normally runs correctly, however when I create a **second** `WebView` with it's own `WebEngine` and try and execute `foo2()` on that **second** page, at about the same time as execution `foo1` on the first page, I get this:

> JSException: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function

I could have a synchronization block, but it seems it should be unnecessary since the webEngines are suppose to be independent, are there other solutions?

Comment: You really should be using a more descriptive title

Answer (score 1):

This is a session management error in your program.

2 WebViews compete for the same session, and ... assuming you haven't implemented protocol and session handlers, including cookie storage, etc..., the second webengine which is unable to obtain the connection will run the script over something that doesn't exist ( as far as the webengine is concerned ) hence an UNDEFINED object.. thus the error.

I'm using this stuff over HTTPS protocols, and have experienced this.